# Работа с шаблонизатором Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Добрый день, всем форумчанам!

У меня стал остро такой вопрос: сказали использовать Smarty и спроектировать новостной сайт на нем. Учитывая, что я с шаблонизаторами не сталкивался раньше, это стало для меня определенной проблемой. Во-первых, я скачал с официального сайта Smarty.net свежую версию 3.1.19. Распаковал ее. Открыл статьи, посвященные установке и работе с этим шаблонизатором. В итоге прочитал, что структура должна быть такая:

```
Smarty-v.e.r/
    libs/
        Smarty.class.php
        Smarty_Compiler.class.php
        Config_File.class.php
        debug.tpl
        internals/*.php (все файлы)
        plugins/*.php (все файлы)
```

В моем случае структура папок и файлов выглядит не так совсем:

```
demo/
libs/
   Smarty.class.php
   SmartyBC.class.php
   debug.tpl
   plugins/ *.php (все файлы)
   sysplugins/ *.php (все файлы)
```

Непонятно, как установить шаблон на этот шаблонизатор и где брать недостающие файлы. 
Вторая просьба к формумчанам: если кто-то работал со Smarty, можете поделиться интересными мыслями на этот счет, статьями и исходниками. Потому что мне на все это дело дали буквально два дня. Надо успеть быстро въехать в это все и спроектировать сайт новостной на этом шаблонизаторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблонизатор подключается к исполняемому файлу:

---

```
<?php

require_once SITE_DIR."libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php";

class Smarty_ extends Smarty {

   function Smarty_(){
        // Конструктор класса.
        // Он автоматически вызывается при создании нового экземпляра.
        $this->Smarty();

        $this->template_dir = SITE_DIR."tpl/";
        $this->compile_dir = SITE_DIR."smarty/compile/";
        $this->config_dir = SITE_DIR."smarty/configs/";
        $this->cache_dir = SITE_DIR."smarty/cache/";

        $this->caching = false;
   } 
}

$smarty = new Smarty_;

//
$smarty->assign("sitename","Smarty site");

$smarty->display("index.tpl");

?>
```

---

В файле tpl/index.tpl можно указывать переменную {$sitename}, которая примет значение 'Smarty site'.

p.s. Smarty хорош, но два дня на него маловато.